# C++ inheritance add operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, operators, addition

I have some problem when i want to make a "+" operator in my Derived class. I have already have a "+" oparator in my Base class.

```
class Base{
    //Some data
public: 
    //Some other function
    Base operator+(const Base& rhs_s) const ;
    Base operator+(char rhs_c) const { return *this + Base(rhs_c);}
    //Some other function
};


class Derived :public Base{
public: 
    Derived () :Base("") {}
    Derived (char c) :Base(c) {}
    Derived (const char* c) :Base(c) {}

    Derived operator+(const Derived& s) const {
        return Derived(*this) + Derived(s);
   }
```

So I can't add two variable where "Derived + 'C'"

I thanks for the help

Comment: Would you care to tell us what the problem is that you're having?

Comment: Sorry, maybe i did not write down. When i want to use that operator for example: 
const Base d("hello");
Derived b;
b = d + 'C';
Giving an error.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, I can do this fine:

```
Derived d{'c'};
const Derived d2 = d + 'C';
```

Your example in the comment is different:

```
const Base d("hello");
Derived b;
b = d + 'C';
```

The above code doesn't compile because  will return a Base object, which cannot be implicitly upcasted to a Derived type. For example:

```
Derived d;
Base b = d; // This is fine because you are going from a more specific type to a less specific one
Derived d2 = b; // This is not okay unless you explicitly define an assignment/constructor for Derived that takes a Base object
```

Comment: The compiler implicitly generates an assignment operator.

Comment: That is true for the same type, but not from Base -> Derived. I agree that my explanation isn't clear enough. Will fix.

Comment: If you really want to assign a Derived object to a Base object, you must overload the assignment operator or constructor in the Derived class to accept a Base object.